# AlpineJS Load More Animation

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I am running into an issue where the load more animation is not getting fired when I have the index set to 10 and I increment by 10, however if i switch the index to 9 and the increment to 9 it runs just fine. On the backend there is a total of 20 so Ideally 10 start on the page and you can load the additional ten or more by clicking the button. I am hoping someone can help me understand why ten doesnt work but 9 does:

```
<div x-data="{ show: false, index: 10 }">
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-5 gap-4 md:gap-6 lg:gap-6 mt-4">
    @foreach($tributes as $tribute)
        <div class="gallery-border p-8" x-show="show && index > {{$loop->index}}" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-500" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100">
            <p class="text-2xl md:text-4xl lg:text-4xl">{{ $tribute->message }}</p>
            <p class="text-sm">-{{ $tribute->name }}</p>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
@if(count($tributes) < $totalTributes)
    <div class="text-center mt-4">
        @if($totalTributes - count($tributes) < 10)
            <button x-on:click="show = true; index = index + {{$totalTributes - count($tributes)}}; $wire.loadMore()" x-init="setTimeout(() => { show = true }, 500)" class="tributes-gallery-load-more">Load More</button>
        @else
            <button x-on:click="show = true; index = index + 10; $wire.loadMore()" x-init="setTimeout(() => { show = true }, 500)" class="tributes-gallery-load-more">Load More</button>
        @endif
    </div>
@endif
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\Tribute;
use Livewire\Component;

class TributeGallery extends Component
{
    public $tributes, $totalTributes;
    public $perPage = 10;
    public $page = 1;

    public function loadMore()
    {
        $this->page++;
        $newTributes = Tribute::where('status', 'approved')
                              ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                              ->skip(($this->page - 1) * $this->perPage)
                              ->take($this->perPage)
                              ->get();

        $this->tributes = $this->tributes->concat($newTributes);

    }

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->totalTributes = Tribute::where('status', 'approved')->count();
        $this->tributes = Tribute::where('status', 'approved')
                                  ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                                  ->take($this->perPage)
                                  ->get();

    }


    public function render()
    {

        return view('livewire.tribute-gallery');
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the whole last batch not load or just the last item?

Comment: Hi Dauros, when I do 10 the whole last batch loads it just doesnt do it with the animation, when I do 9 all but 1 load and the animation does play.

Comment: Strange, so it's not because of the indexing starts from 0. Could you share the `loadMore()` method?

Comment: I added the entire Livewire component to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first page load with a half second delay you switch `show` to `true`. You never switch back this variable to `false` so half of the `x-show` condition is always satisfied for the subsequent loads. The `index` starts from 10 and when you click on the *Load More* button first the `index` variable is increased by 10, so now its 20 and `show` is still `true`. After that you call `$wire.loadMore()` to load the next batch. However since you have already increased the `index` variable and again `show` remains `true` for the whole time, the `x-show="show && index > {{$loop->index}}"` condition already satisfied when Livewire loads the next batch, so Alpine.js will not fire the transition animation since the transition will not occur.

The fix is now straightforward: load the next batch first and just after that increase the `index` variable (optionally with a small delay), so the `x-show` condition can change from `false` to `true` for the new items therefore the transition can occur as well. The `show` variable is redundant and can be removed.

```
<div x-data="{ index: 0 }">
<div class="grid grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-5 gap-4 md:gap-6 lg:gap-6 mt-4">
    @foreach($tributes as $tribute)
        <div class="gallery-border p-8" x-show="index > {{$loop->index}}" x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-500" x-transition:enter-start="opacity-0" x-transition:enter-end="opacity-100">
            <p class="text-2xl md:text-4xl lg:text-4xl">{{ $tribute->message }}</p>
            <p class="text-sm">-{{ $tribute->name }}</p>
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
@if(count($tributes) < $totalTributes)
    <div class="text-center mt-4">
      <button x-on:click="$wire.loadMore(); setTimeout(() => { index = index + 10 }, 500)" class="tributes-gallery-load-more">Load More</button>
    </div>
@endif
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the very detailed answer Dauros! I have dropped this in and I see that load more is adding them to the page, but they are not being shown. All of them are added with display:none style. Could this be the delay issue you mentioned because they are added but show is not being changed to true?

Comment: In my answer I removed the `show` variable, since it's not needed anymore. Have you removed it as well? When the items are loaded we have `x-show="0 > 1"`, `x-show="0 > 2"`, ... `x-show="0 > 9"`, none of them is`true` so they are hidden, then the `index` is increased by 10 so each of them becomes `true`: `x-show="10 > 1"`, `x-show="10 > 2"` etc. and the loading animation is shown.

Comment: I have removed the show variable and i see on page load index is 10 and then when i click load more index is not getting updated to 20 which is definitely the reason we arent showing the new items

Comment: It looks like when x-init="setTimeout(() => { index = index + 10 }, 500)" is called at the initial load and not called again when I click the load more button so we never add 10 to the index

I changed this: <div x-data="{ index: 0 }" x-init="setTimeout(() => { index = index + 10 }, 500)">

and changed the on click to this: <button x-on:click="$wire.loadMore(); setTimeout(() => { index = index + 10 }, 500)" class="tributes-gallery-load-more">Load More</button>

it works but is this a bad approach?

Comment: You're right, I forgot that LW won't execute `x-init` again after the initial loads. I fixed it in my answer. You can try even without the half second delay, I can't test it right now, but if `$wire.loadMore()` is a blocking call, then the delay is not needed.

Comment: I went ahead and removed the delay and it is working like a charm. Thanks for your help troubleshooting the issue and providing a great explanation!